# ValueError at /save_data/

Tags: python, django, django-models

ValueError at /save_data/
Cannot assign "'IT'": "ProfileModel.itype" must be a "IndustriesModel" instance
this is the error i am getting when saving the data to profilemodel could
this is my views.py:

```
def save_data(request):
    ed=request.POST.get("p1")
    ph=request.POST.get("p2")
    re=request.POST.get("p3")
    ty=request.POST.get("p4")
    ProfileModel(education=ed,photo=ph,resume=re,itype=ty).save()
    return render(request,"process_templates/login.html")
```

and the `models.py` :

```
class RegistrationModel(models.Model):
rno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
contact=models.IntegerField(unique=True)
email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
password=models.CharField(max_length=30)
otp=models.IntegerField()
doj=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
status=models.CharField(max_length=30,default="pending")


class IndustriesModel(models.Model):
ino=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
type=models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.type



class ProfileModel(models.Model):
pno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
person=models.OneToOneField(RegistrationModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
education=models.CharField(max_length=100)
photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images/')
resume=models.FileField(upload_to='user_resumes/')
itype=models.OneToOneField(IndustriesModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

could anyone help me solving the issue i am using html not the forms.

Comment: I was trying to save data and it is showing valueerror I don't know why it because of foreign key or one to one field used in the models

Answer (score 0):

Are there other models?

OneToOneField needs to correspond to other models.

Should your table have an itype_id?

```py
ProfileModel(education=ed,photo=ph,resume=re,itype_id=ty).save()
```

[image: img]

Comment: yes there is another model i updated it if u can check it once.

Comment: In addition to itype, the table will also have an itype_id

Comment: First of all, you have to answer me if the ProfileModel has itype and itype_id.

Comment: Profilemodel contains only itype there is no i type_id

Comment: makemigrateions and migrate?

Comment: According to your modes, create a table.